# How can you check / validate the country in the Address Field + Commerce using the user's IP address?

Tags: commerce, location

We've got a UK based Drupal Commerce store and we'd like to:

1. Preselect the Address Field country, based on the user's IP
   address
2. Not let the user continue unless the country they've selected matches the country of the their IP address

The main reason we need this check is because we're using `Commerce EU VAT` and the `VAT Number` modules, and would like to make sure that if the VAT Number is entered, the user is in the country that they say they are, as the system will apply their VAT rate based on location.

I've noticed there are quite a few IP address / location modules available, and the best I could see was `Smart IP`, which integrates with `Rules`, but I can't find a way of adding the above checking / validation to my checkout process. Any help or advice appreciated.

Comment: If you want your users to be able to connect via VPN, Tor, Kindle GSM connection and similar services, you can't. And it will be futile as there are free or cheap VPN services in most countries now, so smart user will have easy way to cheat anyway. Root of the IP assignment documentation is [here](http://www.iana.org/numbers)

Comment: By the way, storing and presenting IP should probably be separate question, as this is Q&A site, and not a forum where you put a broad topic / task as a single thread :)

Comment: I agree - technically, this is possible, but our tax advisor recommended we make this check to prove we've done everything we can to ensure the correct country is entered. Most digital services (Netflix, etc.) seem to make this check so I think it's quite reasonable.

Comment: It's not a fraud to use VPN. When I'm in hotel in Amsterdam, I still connect to the net via VPN in Warsaw if I feel I might need a bag of tricks my little box here offers me ;) When I'm riding in a bus, I use their WiFi and IP I'm seen under is always in Warsaw, even if I'm close to Berlin. When using Kindle 3G, there are 2 or 3 internet gateways in the world. Being unable to select country I'm actually in because your system uses faulty assumptions would be irritating. If you are sure you want to get rid of all these clients, your choice, but in reality you are NOT making sure where user is.

Comment: Like I said, it's a 'reasonable check' i.e. there isn't anything else we can do to check the country at time of purchase, and we were recommended we do this by our tax advisor. We're happy with the commercial implication (which is going slightly off topic now) as we will make this clear up-front and most of our market will be working desk-based. Any advice you can give on this specific issue would be appreciated :)

Comment: Well, either your tax advisor is ignorant about how net works, or he based his advice on the judgment of the ignorant court. But long story short there is no precise IP-to-country service. There are [five registers](http://www.iana.org/_img/2013.1/rir-map.svg) and [some IPs belongs to companies, independent to location](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xml). So you need to decide who's geoip guess / approximation you want to buy (or simply take if it's free). Then we may talk implementation. By the way [I can't forget this](http://xkcd.com/713/) ;)

Comment: Well I'm not sure if we have a choice. Here is the law, as stated by HMRC: "As technology cannot determine with certainty the place where such customers belong, self-declaration by the customer combined with a reasonable level of verification will be acceptable." They state a 'reasonable level' of check as using geo-location software. [Source](http://webarchive.nationalarchives.gov.uk/20110202144320/http://customs.hmrc.gov.uk/channelsPortalWebApp/channelsPortalWebApp.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=pageLibrary_ShowContent&id=HMCE_CL_000914&propertyType=document)

Comment: Well, if that's your law then I can only be sorry for sad legislature, almost as stupid as EU cookie law ;) But the question about who you want to buy geoip guess from is still open ;)

Comment: Lol - I wish there was an easier way. The Smart IP module uses many IP databases, and it seems to work well (it got my location correct). It only needs country accuracy anyway. The issue I'm having is with implementing this with Commerce and Address Field.

Comment: Both [Smart IP](https://drupal.org/project/smart_ip) and [Addressfield Tokens](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield_tokens) modules provide tokens for country. Computed Field or Rules or custom implementation could be used to compare them. Have you tried anything like that yet?

Comment: I've tried to add this through Rules (using `Addressfield Tokens`) but can't find a way. I haven't tried the other modules though.